# How to insert many data in one column

Tags: php, mysql

How to insert many data in one column

example

```
user_log(primary key)         favorite
--------                       ----
       a                       car
       b                       cat
       c                       dog
```

and I want to insert data in `favorite`

this bottom is I want.

```
user_log(primary key)          favorite
--------                       ----
       a                       car
       c                       dog
       a                       home
       a                       swimming
```

I try `INSERT INTO userss (user_log,fav) values ('".$_POST["key"]."','".$_POST["fav"]."')`

> this is error Duplicate entry '..' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: You seem to have a misunderstanding of what a primary key is.

Comment: remove primary key

Comment: A primary key does not allow for duplicate keys so you would need to remove that constraint. Why do you have that here?

Comment: Also you should take a look at http://bobby-tables.com to learn about SQL injection. Your query is really unsafe and to hack your database would be a think of some seconds.

Comment: haha I'm stupid , thanks for your help. >___<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like below i hope its solve you problem.

```
id(primary key)   user_log                  favorite
                   --------                  ----
 1                   a                       car
 2                   c                       dog
 3                   a                       home
 4                   a                       swimming
```

Answer (score 2):

A primary key does not allow for duplicate keys.

Change your Table structure to store data as per your requirement.

Remove Primary key from **user_log** and add one more columns name **id**(as per your requirement) with primary key.

After, run your script.. it's work for you.

[image: You can do same as this.]

Hope u got it :) Enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems same entry key "a". You just have to remove this column as primary key. It can't be same and should be unique.